# How can i make somethig like a label with a scroll bar apper when i press a button

Tags: c#, winforms

how can i do something like this in windows form application. I want to press a button and something like a label to apper filed with some text i want to put in and with a scroll bar. What should i use?
like in this project at image 3: https://www.atestateinformatica.ro/C-plus-plus/Barcelona-730

Comment: It depends to the content which you are trying to show. Take a look at [`WebBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control or a [`RichTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/richtextbox-control-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). You can also host any control in a `Panel` and set its [`AutoScroll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to true.

Comment: I use a Panel, but how i can insert text in that panel by pressing a button?